# cakephp route setting

Tags: url, cakephp, routes

I want to set the cakephp route for URL like this: /param1/contorllername/actionname/ How can I do that, and if I do it, how do I use `$this->redirect(array('controller'=>$controllername,'action'=>$actionname))` to redirect my page. Similarly how do I use `$this->Html->link` for this url.

Answer (score 1):

you can define this in your routes.php

```
Router::connect(
    '/:param1/:controller/:action',
    array(),
    array('pass' => array('param1'))
);
```

Then you can declare route like this

```
$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'view','param1'=>10))
```

This will redirect to /10/posts/view

Comment: Thank you,you message is very help for me.